# Is Fork-Join framework in Java 8 the best option?

Tags: java-8, executorservice, fork-join

I have a scenario like i want to read a spreadsheet which consists of around 2000 records and enter it into database.

Currently we are using Executor framework. We have limitation that no of tasks should be only 5. Each task reads 20 rows from the excel. We provide the start index and end index of the rows to be read from the excel to each task. 
Say, currently, 
Task 1 handles 1-20
Task-2 handles 21-40
Task-3 handles 41-60
Task-4 handles 61-80
Task-5 handles 81-100
If Task-1 finishes its execution, it takes the next 20 rows thats 101-120.
 Suppose if Task-2 finishes before Task-1, it will start reading from 121-140 and not 101-120.

Can i handle this scenario more effectively in a Fork-Join framework only with the restriction of 5 tasks and each task 20 rows?

Need some insight into the performance issues.

Comment: I don’t see any reason to change the framework.

Comment: Right now, the handling of tasks, right now is done by the code which we have designed, i.e. if task 1 is over, allocating the next task is done by the custom code. Does the fork-join framework has any efficient way of handling this by itself? And also we insert a delay to wait till all tasks are completed to get the results. Does the fork-join framework handles this by itself?

Answer (score 3):

No need to switch the thread pool. To make the load more balanced you can just maintain atomic variable which points to the first not taken row:

```
AtomicInteger currentRow = new AtomicInteger(); // shared between tasks
final int maxRow = 2000;
final int batchSize = 20;

// Inside every task:
while(true) {
    int row = currentRow.getAndAdd(batchSize);
    if(row >= maxRow) return;
    int from = row+1;
    int to = Math.min(row+batchSize, maxRow);
    // process rows from..to; it's guaranteed that other threads
    // do not process the same rows.
}
```

The body of every task is absolutely the same. Also this implementation does not depend on number of tasks created. If you later decide to have 3 tasks or 7 tasks, just adjust the thread pool size and submit more (or less) tasks.

Comment: Currently, this framework is used for reading from db and writing to google spreadsheet. The problem is when we write, the first task fetches 100 rows from db, filters the data based on custom logic and writes the resulting rows alone to spreadsheet. So for the second task to start writing, we need to wait till the first task completes to know from which row the second task should start writing. Hence i was wondering, if the fork-join framework handles this situation by itself. How is the work stealing algorithm working in Fork-join?